# No Component Names in React Native Web Debugging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-devtools

When trying to debug React Native within the web browser, I am unable to see any Component names. Whether via standard browser DevTools or the React (Component) browser extension, I do not see any reference to the Component names or even the classNames.

Component names are obfuscated by `View`, `Anonymous`, `Screen`, etc in the React extension. Part of that how the code is written using React Native's default`View` and `Screen` components. But I would expect to see the child components nested eventually.

[image]

CSS classes are in `css-xyz123` format, seemingly unrelated to their actual Component and class names.

[image]

Anyone know why this is occurring or how to get the Component names visible for web debugging? I considered a few causes:

- How the components are written (functional components, often wrapped with Mobx observers)
- Babel compiler settings
- Other minifiction or React Native build settings

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A component name like "Anonymous (ForwardRef)" means your source code probably looks something like this:

```
const Component = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {...});
```

The function passed to `forwardRef` is an *anonymous* function, so there is no name for DevTools to read. (Note that this will also be true for built-in browser tooling.)

To "fix" this, you can use a named function. There are two options:

```
const Component = React.forwardRef(function MyComponent(props, ref) {...});
```

Or:

```
const MyComponent = (props, ref) => {...};
const Component = React.forwardRef(MyComponent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestions, @bvaughn!

I love the idea about `forwardRef` & anonymous functions. Unfortunately, that `const Component = React.forwardRef` does not seem to be the culprit as I am not using `forwardRef`. 

For reference, here are a few examples of component declaration structures I'm using often.

Ex 1, Mobx observer`export const MyComponentMemo = observer(function MyComponentMemo_({
  etc
}: MyComponentProps) {`
Ex 2,
`export const MyListView = ({ sort }: MyListViewProps) => {`
Ex 3,
`export const MyComponent = ({ prop1, prop2 }: MyComponentProps) => {`